# Does Kundalini Shakti once awakened cures all major disorders of mind and body?

Tags: tantra

Kundalini Jagran is considered as one of the  greatest experience of one's life. 
Does an awakened Kundalini cures diseases of body and mind? How does this  happen? How safe it is to awaken the Kundalini Shakti?

Comment: in one word - no.

Comment: unless you have gone through the proper training with a qualified guru, it can lead to madness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

“As one opens the door with a key, so the yogi should open the gate to liberation with the kundalini. The great goddess sleeps, closing with her mouth,, the opening through which one can ascend to the brahrnarandhra... to that place where there is neither pain nor suffering. The kundalini sleeps above the kanda... she gives liberation to the yogi and bondage to the fool. He who knows kundalini, knows yoga. The kundalini, it is said, is coiled like a serpent- He who can induce her to move is liberated." Hatha Yoga Pradipika v. 105-111.

The above quote sums up the immense value of Kundalini in the process of spiritual evolution.

Swami Vivekananda sums up the whole question of kundalini as a universal phenomena when he states, "When by the power of long internal meditation, the vast mass of energy stored up, travels along the sushumna and strikes the chakras, the reaction is immensely more intense than any reaction of sense perception. Wherever there was any manifestation of what is ordinarily called supernatural power or wisdom, there a little current of kundalini must have found its way into the Sushamna”.

By means of kundalini awakening, you are compensating with the laws of nature and speeding up the pace of your physical, mental and spiritual evolution. Once the great shakti awakens, man is no longer a gross physical body operating with a lower mind and low voltage prana. Instead, every cell of his body is charged with the high voltage prana of kundalini. And when total awakening occurs, man becomes a junior god, an embodiment of divinity.

With the awakening of kundalini, a transformation takes place in life. It has little to do with one's moral, religious or ethical life. It has more to do with the quality of our experiences and perceptions. When kundalini wakes up your mind changes and your priorities and attachments also change. All your karmas undergo a process of integration.

Everybody, whether householder or sannyasin, must remember that awakening of kundalini is the prime purpose of human incarnation. All the pleasures of sensual life which we are enjoying now are intended only to enhance the awakening of kundalini amidst the adverse circumstances of man's life.

There are plenty of ways to awaken Kundalini such as spontaneous, Shaktipath from a Guru, Japa/mantra meditation, self-enquiry(jnana marga),Raja Yoga,Kriya Yoga, Bhakti Yoga or even from substance abuse

But for all practical reasons,regular, sincere practice and proper guidance by a competent master balances the nadis and eventually awakens kundalini.

Note: Source and credit to Sri Swami Satyananda Saraswati’s “Kundalini Tantra”.